# protocol other than TCP and UDP in NetworkExtensions framework

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp, macos-catalina

In the [NetworkExtensions framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) on macOS, the only 2 protocols available in configuration are TCP and UDP.

For example, to write a firewall, apple recommends using [NEFilterRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterrule) and [NENetworkRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nenetworkrule). An [NENetworkRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nenetworkrule) takes a protocol as an argument, and the only available values are TCP or UDP.

What happens if a rogue application on the machine with the firewall tries to communicate with the outside world via another protocol? Maybe a custom protocol with no clear rules. Does the NetworkExtension framework allow filtering these cases?